# getting the screen size of an android virtual device using Qt

Tags: android, qt, android-virtual-device

All,

'am running the following code snippet in Qt to get the screen size of my android virtual device.

```html
QApplication app(argc, argv);
 
 QDesktopWidget *mydesk = app.desktop();
    // redundant but using both showFullScreen and showMaximized...
    // ...just to play it safe
    mydesk->showMaximized();
    mydesk->showFullScreen(); 

  QScreen *screen = app.primaryScreen();
    int width = screen->size().width();
    int height = screen->size().height();
```

I created a Nexus 5 Android Virtual Device with resolution 1080x1920 to test my code and my width and height values are 1080x1776 instead of the expected 1080x1920. What 'am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get screen size with this simple line of code:

```
QRect rect = qApp->primaryScreen()->geometry();
```

Comment: Thanks @evgeny. But I have already tried                      app.primaryScreen()->size().width(). This is the same as your suggestion. My issue is that I get 1080x1776 when I created an AVD that is 1080x1920.